# one thread takes 2 sec , 10 threads take 16-18 secs. why?

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

Each of my threads sleep for 2000 ms , and i have 10 such threads , so i expected the total sleep time to be atleast 20 secs , but its only coming up in between 16-18 secs. Sorry if i'm asking something that has already been asked . Here's what i have so far :

```
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class MyThreadPoolApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long execTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            executor.submit(new Task());
        }
        System.out.println("threads submitted and waiting execution");

        executor.shutdown();        
        try {
            executor.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
        execTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - execTime;
        System.out.format("%d threads finished execution \n",Task.getCount());
        System.out.println("thread time : " + Task.getTime());
        System.out.println("main time : " + execTime);

    }
}
```

Where Task is :

```
public class Task implements Runnable {

    private static long totalTime; 
    private static int count; 
    public static long getTime(){ return totalTime; }
    public static int getCount(){ return count; }

    public void run() {
        count++;
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            totalTime += System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    }
}
```

My output :

```
threads submitted and waiting execution  
10 threads finished execution   
thread time : 18001  
main time : 2020
```

Comment: You're catching `InterruptedException` and not doing anything with it. Do you think it's possible something is going wrong there and it aborts the sleep?

Comment: good point. I didn't think about it. i'll try it out.
@Michael Nope , nothing there..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are messing with concurrent update of totalTime by various threads.

Try this:

```
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class MyThreadPoolApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long execTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            executor.submit(new Task());
        }
        System.out.println("threads submitted and waiting execution");

        executor.shutdown();
        try {
            executor.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
        execTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - execTime;
        System.out.format("%d threads finished execution \n",Task.getCount());
        System.out.println("thread time : " + Task.getTime());
        System.out.println("main time : " + execTime);
    }
}

class Task implements Runnable {

    private static long totalTime;
    private static int count;
    public static long getTime(){
        synchronized(Task.class){
            return totalTime;
        }
    }
    private static void addTime(long time){
        synchronized(Task.class){
            totalTime = totalTime + time;
        }
    }
    public static int getCount(){ return count; }

    public void run() {
        count++;
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            addTime(System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
As you wish, synchronize inside run() method:

```
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class MyThreadPoolApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long execTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            executor.submit(new Task());
        }
        System.out.println("threads submitted and waiting execution");

        executor.shutdown();
        try {
            executor.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
        execTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - execTime;
        System.out.format("%d threads finished execution \n",Task.getCount());
        System.out.println("thread time : " + Task.getTime());
        System.out.println("main time : " + execTime);
    }
}

class Task implements Runnable {

    private static long totalTime;
    private static int count;
    public static long getTime(){
        synchronized(Task.class){
            return totalTime;
        }
    }
    public static int getCount(){ return count; }

    public void run() {
        count++;
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            synchronized(Task.class){
                totalTime += System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what if synchronized be placed inside the run() method ? will save the two additional synch methods wont it ?

Comment: Yes you can put synchronize block inside run() method to update total time! BUT synchronize on Task.class only, because you are updating class variable.